# Python reading from a socket with a multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, sockets, udp, queue, multiprocessing

I am reading from a device that is constantly sending data at a socket, and I am using a multiprocessing queue as a service queue. The code is hardware dependent but essentially:

```
def save_package(dirs, data_queue, end_queue):
    fp = None
    prev_yaw = -100
    while end_queue.empty():
        if data_queue.empty():
            #print 's_p passed'
            pass
        else:
            msg = data_queue.get()
            data = msg['data']
            ts = msg['time']
            yaw = msg['yaw']
            if yaw != prev_yaw:  # Here is where it stops writing
                if fp is not None:
                    fp.close()
                file_fmt = os.path.join(dirs, str(yaw))
                path = str(file_fmt) + '.bin'
                fp = open(path, 'ab')
            else:
                fp.write('%.6f' % ts)
                fp.write(data)
            prev_yaw = yaw


def capture(port, data_queue, end_queue, dirs):
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    soc.bind(('', port))
    cnt = 0
    take_points = 1000
    yaw = 0
    try:
        while True:
            if cnt == take_points:  # Here is where it stops writing
                yaw += 100
                cnt = 0
            else:
                cnt += 1
                data = soc.recv(2000)
                if not end_queue.empty():
                    soc.close()
                    os.system('kill $PPID')
                    os._exit(2)
                    return
                if len(data) > 0:
                    assert len(data) == 1206, len(data)
                    data_queue.put({'data': data, 'time': time.time(), 'yaw': yaw})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dirs = '..'
    processA = Process(target = capture, args = (PORT, DATA_QUEUE, END_QUEUE, dirs))
    processA.start()
    processB = Process(target = save_package, args = (dirs, DATA_QUEUE, END_QUEUE))
    processB.start()
    while True:
        while (processA.is_alive() == True or processB.is_alive() == True):
        os._exit(2)
        os.system('kill $PPID')
        quit()
```

The code is supposed to divide data in 1000 points for each value of yaw variable, but there is certain "mixing" of data - I can see that both visually and according to time stamps. It seems that first 77 packets of each file except the first come from the previous yaw, and is mismatched with the name.

Since the number is unusually constant, I am hoping someone can spot some essential error on my side, since according to manufacturers it cannot be the device.

Is there a way the data can get mixed up that someone can see?
Thanks for you help guys.

EDIT: I've found this answer that seems to have the same problem: [Delay when receiving UDP packets in Python in real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478913/delay-when-receiving-udp-packets-in-python-in-real-time)
If this is the same problem as it seems, can someone explainthe calculation between buffer of 2000, message length of 1206 and 77 pakcets delay?

Comment: It seems like the obvious thing to do here is to dump the data at each step: what you read off the socket, what you put on the queue, what you pop off the queue, and what you write to the outfile. (You can log them to stderr, or store them in four text files, or whatever.) Then you'll know at which step things are going wrong, and you can reduce the problem to something involving just that step and easier to debug.

Comment: I think I did do that, that is how I saw the mismatch. That is also how I know it is ALWAYS first 77 points which are mixed up.

Comment: If you did that, at which of those points do things get mixed up?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if I open the file "500.bin", first 77 points belong to "400.bin" (and yaw=400) while the remainder is as it should be. This happens for every file except the first one, which is completely ok.
You might say things go wrong exactly after the first file (1000 points).

Comment: OK, but when you print out the values that you read off the socket, are they correct, or are they already wrong?

Comment: Oh, ok. That is very difficult to tell as it is binary data that is collected with immense speed (millions of points per second), but according to timestamps it seems ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176596/discussion-between-cindy-almighty-and-abarnert).