# Python UDP socket significant delay between packets

Tags: python, sockets, udp, python-sockets

I'm writing a program to measure throughput between a client and a server. However, the transfer speed is extremely low, where there seems to be some kind of bottleneck in my algorithm that I'm not aware of (at least compared to the TCP counterpart that is over 4 times faster).

I tested with a few combinations of a 1MB message:

- 1024 x 1024 Byte messages: 5.661 Mbps (time delta = 1,481,729,239 ns)
- 2048 x 512 Byte messages: 2.965 Mbps (time delta = 2,829,176,990 ns)
- 4096 x 256 Byte messages: 1.464 Mbps (time delta = 5,731,879,418 ns)

The more messages with a smaller message size are sent, the worse the result (due to the accumulated latency).

I wonder what I might be doing wrong here, or whether if I could have done something differently?

Edit 1: I did some more testing and measurements, and I found out that the bottleneck is the line `sock.recvfrom(message_size)` on the `server.py` file, where there are huge delays between each `recvfrom` but I don't know what is the reason behind it. I attempted to increase/decrease buffer size as well as adding `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 1)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478913/delay-when-receiving-udp-packets-in-python-in-real-time) but nothing changed.

Edit 2: I used Wireshark and found out that there is a massive delay between each packets sent for some reason. Most likely not the server's fault because I tested versus multiple hosts too.[image: Delay!]

The `client.py`:

```
def tp_udp(host: str, port: int, message_size: int, message_count: int):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    data = f"{message_size} {message_count}"
    sock.sendto(bytes(data, "utf-8"), (host, port))

    message = os.urandom(message_size)

    for i in range(0, message_count):
        sock.sendto(message, (host, port))

    sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    sock.close()
```

The `server.py`:

```
def tp_udp(port: int):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(("", port))

    try:
        while True:
            message_data, address = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            message_data = message_data.decode("utf-8")
            message_size = int(message_data.split(" ")[0])
            message_count = int(message_data.split(" ")[1])

            t1 = time.perf_counter_ns()
            counter = 0
            while counter < message_count:
                sock.recvfrom(message_size)
                counter += 1
            t2 = time.perf_counter_ns()

            typer.echo("[SERVER] All messages have been received")
            time_delta = t2 - t1
            throughput = (int(message_count) * int(message_size) * 10 ** 3 * 8) / time_delta
            print(f"Time elapsed: {time_delta} ns")
            print(f"Throughput: {round(throughput, 3)} Mbps")
    except socket.error as error:
        sock.shutdown(socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.close()
```

Comment: Hey @Mint - it might help if you put some numbers to it all - what is your time delta -- how many packets, etc..

Comment: @MrR I updated with a few test results. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Hey @Mint - have you tried increasing the size of the receive buffer - what does that do to it?

Comment: @MrR I did, but unfortunately it didn't change anything, performance is still just as bad. I tried with 2048, 4096, and 8192.

Comment: Did you intend to send message_size and message_count as separate packets?  That seems odd, and it’s likely that a packet will be dropped causing or delivered in the wrong order, causing you to sometimes receive message_size data into your message_count variable (and vice versa)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes, that was intended, but indeed that was an oversight of mine. Thankfully I have been testing with 1024/1024 messages so it hasn't affected anything yet. I've updated the code slightly to reflect your suggestion.